# user not being correct set by useAuth() hook causing screens to be stuck in a protected state

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-context, react-native-navigation

I am building a react native application using expo and am trying to add authentication via context to the rest of the app.
The application does correctly sign in and I get confirmation via console.log in my AuthStack when the form submits, and in my Firebase console; however, to handle rendering the rest of the application I seem to be stuck in the login screen.

useAuth.js
Here I create a use auth hook and sign in props to pass into my AuthStackScreens so I may intiate a log in. Which then gets passed to the context so that application can consume it.

```js
 // ... imports



 const AuthContext = createContext({})  
 
 
 export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loadingInitial, setLoadingInitial] = useState(true)

  //implicitly returns an unsubscribe
  useEffect(
    () => 
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {      
    if(user) {
        //logged in
        setUser(user);
        

      } else {

        setUser(null)
      }

      setLoading(false)
      setLoadingInitial(false)

    }),
    []
  );
    

  const signIn = async(userEmail, userPassword) => {
      try {
        const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword );
        setUser(userCredential.user);       
       
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error('error Signing in ', error.message);
      }
    }  
    const memoedValue = useMemo(() => ({
      user, 
      loading,       
      signIn
    }), [user, loading, error ] )
  
    console.log("auth" , user)
   return (
     <AuthContext.Provider
      value={memoedValue}
     >
     {!loadingInitial && children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
   )
 }
 
 export default function useAuth() {

 
  return useContext(AuthContext);
  
 }
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

```js
// ... (imports)

const AuthStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

//Schema to send data for auth

export const loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
  .string()
  .email("Invalid Email Format")
  .required("Email is a Required Field"),
  password: yup.string().required("Password is a Required field"),
})
// Handle Error 
function  ErrorText  ({ name, errors}) {
  if (!errors) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <View style={{paddingLeft: 8, color: "red"}}>
      {errors[name] && (
        <Text style={{color:'#d81010'}}>{errors?.[name]?.message}</Text>
      )}


    </View>
  );
};
//Receive and deploy error
const ErrorAlert = ({title, message}) =>
  Alert.alert(title, message, [
    {text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("ok Pressed")}
  ])
//Condense setting data in state 
export  function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
  const{ signIn, loading } = useAuth()


  //stores form inputs
  const {
    register, 
    setValue, 
    getValues, 
    handleSubmit, 
    // control, 
    // reset, 
    formState:  {errors},
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(loginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: "",
    },
  });

  useEffect (() => {
      register("email");
      register("password");
  }, [] )


// handles log in
 async function doLogin (data) {
      const { email, password} = data
      
      console.log(data)
      try {
        await signIn(email, password)
        console.log("signed In!!!")
          // commented out navigation as per react navigation auth flow discourages manual   navigation after on log in, should be handled by authcontext

        // navigation.navigate('HomeTabs')
       
      }
      catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error Logging In', error.message);
      }
  }
  

  
  // unused function 
  function onConfirmHandler() {
    // Confirm sign in 
    //navigate to home
    // navigation.navigate(HomeScreen)
    
  }
  function onPressSignUp () {
    navigation.navigate("SignUpScreen")
  }


  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Email</Text>
      <TextInput 
      id="email"
      textContentType='emailAddress'
      autoCapitalize='none'
      style={styles.input}
      onChangeText={(text)=> setValue("email", text)}      
      />
      
      <ErrorText name="email" errors={errors}> </ErrorText>
      <Text> Password</Text>
      <TextInput 
      id="password"
      textContentType='password'
      secureTextEntry={true}
      style={styles.input}
      autoCapitalize='none'
      onChangeText={(text)=> setValue("password", text)}
     
      
      />
      
      
      <ErrorText name="password" errors={errors}> </ErrorText>
      
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}> 
      <Button  style={styles.button}onPress={handleSubmit(doLogin)} > Log In </Button>
     
      <Text  style={styles.buttonText}> Don't have an account? </Text>

      <Button style={styles.button} onPress={onPressSignUp} > Create Account </Button>

      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
//sign up currently work in progress after log in becomes successful 
export  function SignUpScreen({navigation}) {
 ...


function AuthStackScreens() {
  return <AuthStack.Navigator > 
    <AuthStack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen}/>
    <AuthStack.Screen name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen}/>
    {/* navigate to profilecreate screen? */}
 
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
}

export default AuthStackScreens

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 // ... styling

})
```

Here the signIn does currently work, the form submits, and the console.log in useAuth.js fires I do see that I get all the user data.

```js
// ...imports


const MainStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} />,
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStackScreens}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="person" color={color} size={size} />,
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStackScreens() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();
// console.log returns undefined for user, fires first when app builds
  console.log(user, loading)
  if (loading) {
    return <View><Text>loading. .. .</Text></View>;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
          <UsersContextProvider>
            <MainStack.Navigator>
              {user ? (
                <>
                  <MainStack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <MainStack.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CardDetails} />
                  <MainStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreens} />
                  <MainStack.Screen name="ProfileCreateScreen" component={ProfileCreateScreen} />
                </>
              ) : (
                <MainStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreens} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              )}
            </MainStack.Navigator>
          </UsersContextProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthProvider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Now here Is where I believe the problem lies, I am using nested navigators, and I think the problem lies with how I am trying to make AuthProvider be a Higer Order Component. Which I think I am doing correctly. I suspect the problem is that the useAuth hook in app.js  does not update when the rest of the other components do their sign in. I have tried to refactor using a useReducer in my useAuth.js but that did not work either. After many hours of research, I am wondering if anyone else can provide a fresh set of eyes. Thank you.

EDIT:

So after seperating the navigational components into separate files, the useAuth check happens in MainStackScreen component file instead of app.js, this way app, can fire first and correctly look to other components. After making these changes sign in to go to home screens correctly works.